# PHP While loop to display information in groups of four

Tags: php, html, database, slider

I want to make a slider that displays four boxes at a time with information in it.
I connect to the database and get information to then output it using a while loop. Is it possible to output it in groups of four, seeing as I only have four boxes and repeat the process as many times as it takes.
So far I can output four boxes but only for one person...

```
<?php
    include '../pinFlow/configuration.php';
    session_start();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pin WHERE pin_profession = 'Engineering' order by pinID desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
    while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>
      <figure>
        <img src="../pinFlow/userfiles/avatars/<?php echo $rws['pin_avatar'];?>" class="active" />
        <figcaption><?php echo $rws['name'];?></figcaption>
        <img src="../pinFlow/userfiles/avatars/<?php echo $rws['pin_avatar'];?>" class="active" />
        <figcaption><?php echo $rws['name'];?></figcaption>
        <img src="../pinFlow/userfiles/avatars/<?php echo $rws['pin_avatar'];?>" class="active" />
        <figcaption><?php echo $rws['name'];?></figcaption>
      </figure>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You can use a counter and the modulus operator `%`

Comment: Use `mysqli_result->fetch_all()` with a regular for loop. `+= 4` the increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fetch all resulting dataset and then split it up in groups of length 4, using `array_chunk`:

```
<?php
include '../pinFlow/configuration.php';
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pin WHERE pin_profession = 'Engineering' order by pinID desc";
$result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
$all = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$groups = array_chunk($all, 4);
foreach ($groups as $group) {?>
  <figure>
    <?php foreach ($group as $rws) { ?>
    <img src="../pinFlow/userfiles/avatars/<?php echo $rws['pin_avatar'];?>" class="active" />
    <figcaption><?php echo $rws['name'];?></figcaption>
    <?php }?>
  </figure>
  <?php } ?>
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Oh yeah, Thank you so much! one problem though, it doesn't output any names or images... I'm kinda a noob in php.

Comment: Updated the answer. Turns out the default mode of `mysqli_fetch_all` is `MYSQLI_NUM`. Should be `MYSQLI_ASSOC` in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much!